# Can light be sped up to go 30 times fast than the speed of light in a medium?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction

Here's the link: https://sciencebulletin.org/researchers-develop-way-to-control-speed-of-light-send-it-backward/

Here's the line that makes no sense to me: Abouraddy and study co-author Esat Kondakci demonstrated they could speed a pulse of light up to 30 times the speed of light...

Need some help on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it makes no sense.

It's bad reporting, and I'd go so far as to say that the researchers involved failed to make it clear that what they demonstrated was *not* a way to make anything actually go faster than $c$.  What they showed is crudely analogous to standing on the Earth and zig-zagging a laser beam back and forth across the moon a few hundred times per second.  Sure, the point where the beam illuminates the moon moves some tens of times faster than $c$.  *But nothing is conveyed from point A to point B* on the moon in that scenario.  Instead, light is conveyed from the laser on Earth to point A and to point B.  Make light travel backwards? Easy: just sweep the laser from B to A.

In the paper, the authors do say "The group velocity here is the speed of the wave packet central spatio-temporal intensity peak, whereas the wave packet energy remains spread over its entire spatio-temporal extent.".  Their definition would equally well describe a laser spot flying across the Moon.  It definitely does not describe a situation where energy flows from point A to point B.